# Identify image offset between two similar image C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, aforge, image-compression

I have two images. One is a original image (source image), and the other is a scanned copy of original image. I need to compare the two images find offset (X, Y) is created by the scanned copy.

In different scenarios I am getting different offset from top and let.

I want to compare these images and trying to find offset automatically.

I am about to start coding for this so I do not have any code snippet available with me. We do have reference of AForge Library / EgmuCV in our project, any suggestion using these libraries would be good for me.

Comment: Do you have an snippet of the code you are using? Are you using a framework or library?

Comment: Any suggestion using AForge would be good for me. I have updated my question.

Comment: Start from [ExhaustiveBlockMatching](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/05d0ab7d-a1ae-7ea5-9f7b-a966c7824669.htm)